# Adding more than 1 criteria into "find_all" for searching HTML code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get BeautifulSoup to search for the following tags:

```
<a>
<span class="badge capita-voucher">
<span class="badge halal">
```

How should I express my requirements in my first line of code? Is the code that I have typed below appropriate?

```
for cell in row.find_all(['a', ("span", {"class":"badge capita-voucher"}), ("span", {"class":"badge halal"})]):
                line_bs_object = BeautifulSoup(cell.__str__(), "html.parser")
                csvRow.append(
                    line_bs_object.get_text().strip().replace('\\n', '').replace('\\r', '')
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this by [passing a function as the filtering parameter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to `find_all`:

```
def is_tag_interesting(tag):
    is_interesting = False
    if tag.name == 'a':
        is_interesting = True
    elif tag.name == 'span' and 'badge' in tag.class:
        if any(s in tag.class for s in ('halal', 'capita-voucher')):
            is_interesting = True
    return is_interesting

for cell in row.find_all(is_tag_interesting):
    ...
```